VM authenticating on its host machine with incorrect credentials causing the lockout of a local account
I have a Windows 11 machine hosting a Hyper-V Windows 11 VM. Both the host machine and VM have been using a local administrator account with the same username and password. The password for this account on the host machine was changed. The password on the VM was not changed. This precipitated account lockouts on the host machine. Event logs on the host machine evidenced account login failures originating from the VM. The lockouts were resolved by changing the username of the account on the VM although event logs on the host machine still showed login failures for the new account name.
Is this expected behaviour?
Why is the VM authenticating with the administrator account on the host machine?
Is it necessary for accounts with the same name on a VM and its host machine to also have the same password to avoid an account lockout situation?


Is this expected behaviour?

Yes, it is. Windows transparently attempts to use "pass-through" authentication in many activities.

Is it necessary for accounts with the same name on a VM and its host machine to also have the same password to avoid an account lockout situation?

This is dependent on what is occurring. If one host is accessing resources on another host, yes.

I can't figure out exactly what the VM is trying to authenticate on the host machine. There are shortcuts on the VM's (personal) desktop to shared folders on the host machine but they aren't mapped as network drives. I am wondering whether something is authenticating that is intrinsic to Hyper-V?

@GuruJosh: This isn't specific to Hyper-V. Windows automatically does this for any resource that it is attempting to access. You know this because you can setup two vanilla Windows test hosts and reproduce the behavior. In summary, it must be authenticated, and if the credentials that are automatically presented are incorrect or are unknown, the authentication fails.
